# mongodb aggregation "$in" operator: how can i address the path to all nested array elements inside an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

So i want to check if an element is in few arrays. the number of arrays can change between 2 to 4. the structure of data is as follows:

```
    {"question" : {
    "answers" : [ 
        {
            "answerText" : "7000",
            "_answerVotes" : []
        }, 
        {
            "answerText" : "15000",
            "_answerVotes" : []
        }, 
        {
            "answerText" : "45000",
            "_answerVotes" : []
        }, 
        {
            "answerText" : "80000",
            "_answerVotes" : []
        }
    ],
    "expireTime" : ISODate("2022-12-14T15:58:11.453Z")
}}
```

aggregation stage:

```
        (addFields.isUserVotedAnswerd = {
      $cond: {
        if: {
          $in: [ObjectId(user), "question.answers.$._answerVotes"],
        },
        //   $or: [
        //     { $in: [ObjectId(user), "$question.answers.0._answerVotes"] },
        //     { $in: [ObjectId(user), "$question.answers.1._answerVotes"] },
        //     { $in: [ObjectId(user), "$question.answers.2._answerVotes"] },
        //     { $in: [ObjectId(user), "$question.answers.3._answerVotes"] },
        //   ],
        // },
        then: true,
        else: false,
      },
    }),
```

Tried both approaches. And I keep getting this error:
"$in requires an array as a second argument, found: string "

Anybody know how to address this?
Many thanks

Comment: Are you trying to ask if `_answersvotes` is present in at least one item in  the `answers` array?

Comment: i am trying to see if the user id is in one of the  _answerVotes arrays. the answers array could have 2-4 elements. this is unknown

Answer (score 0):

Given this input:

```
var r = [
    {question: {
        "answers" : [
            {"answerText" : "7000", "_answerVotes" : ["U1"] },
            {"answerText" : "15000", "_answerVotes" : ["U2","U7"] }
    ]
    }},

    {question: {
         "answers" : [
             {"answerText" : "7000", "_answerVotes" : ["U2"] },
             {"answerText" : "15000", "_answerVotes" : ["U9"] }
         ]
    }},

    {question: {
         "answers" : [
             {"answerText" : "7000", "_answerVotes" : ["U7"] }
         ]
    }}

];
```

then the following will select only those docs where at least one user ID in any of the `_answerVotes` in the `answers` array matches the target:

```
var target_user = 'U2';  // user is string here but could be ObjectId

db.foo.aggregate([
    {$project: {'X': {$filter: {input: '$question.answers',
                                as: 'z',
                                cond: {$in:[target_user,'$$z._answerVotes']}
                     }}
    }}
    ,{$match: {$expr: {$ne:[0,{$size:'$X'}] } }}
]);
```

Comment: thanks for effort. but i am not trying to add a field and determinate if it true or false according to the question if the userid is in an nested array when the first array has unknown elements. my biggest issue is not knowing how to address the second array in the "$in" operator